# Missing letters in zathura's search

Tags: freebsd, keyboard, zathura

So I use the following Zathura version under FreeBSD 10.3

```
$ zathura --version
zathura 0.3.4
(plugin) pdf-mupdf (0.2.9) (/usr/local/lib/zathura/pdf.so)
```

I remember that some time ago an earlier version of Zathura under Linux worked fine. But now I have the following extremely annoying problem:

If I open a pdf document and search it with <kbd>/</kbd> and type the search term fast<sup>1</sup> then some of the letters of the search term go *missing.*

So this is not like the usual mildly annoying keyboard stuttering in which case the letters appear after some delay. It is far worse: it stuttering and the letters don't appear anymore.

---

<sup>1</sup> well not really fast, the problem happens well before 300 kpm. And it depends on the document. If it is a heavy 20 MB pdf file, the problem already exists with extremely slow typing.

Comment: I've had same problem on Linux too.

Comment: @uzsolt: you ***had*** the same problem? :-) Did you solve it?

Comment: I'm not using Linux anymore so I don't have this problem on Linux :) But on FreeBSD this problem exists too. I want to try slowly type ;) And I search in pdf files rarely.

Comment: That's clearly a bug (either in Zathura or in a library that it uses). Have you checked if it's fixed in the latest version? Have you checked if it's already been reported?

Comment: @Gilles: indeed, the bug disappears after upgrading the girara library.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats you might like to add that as an answer and mark it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in the Girara library, which Zathura uses. It is still present in the version 0.2.5.

So to fix the problem, download version 0.2.6 of Girara from [here](https://pwmt.org/projects/girara/download/), compile and install.